# R Duplicate Join Function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I was running into a problem using dplyr's join functions when I had duplicate values and wanted to keep the first value, so I decided to write my own function. If there's a function that already does this, please let me know! It's probably much better written and effective.

Here is the code with some sample data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(A = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), B = rep(1:3, 2),
                  C = runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 10))
dt2 <- data.table(A = c(rep(3, 3), rep(4, 3)), B = rep(1:3, 2),
                  C = runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 10))
dt3 <- data.table(A = c(rep(3, 3), rep(4, 3)), B = rep(1:3, 2),
                  D = runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 10))
dt4 <- data.table(A = c(rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3)), B = rep(1:3, 2),
                  D = runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 10))

dt5 <- duplicate_join(dt1, dt2)
dt6 <- duplicate_join(dt5, dt3)
dt7 <- duplicate_join(dt6, dt4)

duplicate_join <- function(dt1, dt2) {

  melt1 <- dt1 %>%
    gather(variable, value, -c(A, B), na.rm = TRUE)
  melt2 <- dt2 %>%
    gather(variable, value, -c(A, B), na.rm = TRUE)

  join <- rbindlist(list(melt1, melt2), use.names = TRUE) %>%
    distinct(A, B, variable, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    spread(variable, value)
  join
}
```

My problem is letting the user decide which columns to gather and check for duplicate values. In this case to make `A` and `B` into a generic expression. I've read on [Functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html), [Capturing Un-evaluated Dots](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-dots), and looked at some source code of functions that do this (`ggplot`), but nothing is making sense. I've tried a lot of techniques and get errors `object 'A' not found` or `invalid argument to unary operator`.

It doesn't matter to me whether the function call is:

```
duplicate_join <- function(dt1, dt2, ...) {}
```

Or:

```
duplicate_join <- function(dt1, dt2, cols) {}
```

I just need to know how to get the `...` or `cols` to work within the function! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Semi Join](http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html) From Dplyr Package

Description:

> semi_join(x, y): Return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, keeping just columns from x. A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will return one row of x for each matching row of y, where a semi join will never duplicate rows of x. This is a filtering join.

Using your code here is an example of semi_join:

```
#Semi Joining by equality of "B" Columns, Keeping dt1, 
#if you want to keep dt2, just change the parameters order
dt4 <- semi_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("B" = "B"))

Output:

  A B         C
1 1 1 5.3330819
2 2 1 0.1652472
3 1 2 4.6283878
4 2 2 1.5570931
5 1 3 9.6967720
6 2 3 1.1587919

#Semi Joining: Multiple Columns
dt5 <- semi_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("A" = "A", "B" = "B"))
#No output, there's no rows that satisfy "A" = "A" and "B" = "B"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Cayoda! Unfortunately, `semi_join` will not work because, as your example shows, it does not work for the multiple column case. It really does not work in the first case, as it changed the values in column 'A.'